# Groß-/Kleinschreibung von "Soziales Netzwerk"

Tags: capitalization

Ich bin beim Schreiben gerade über den Begriff *Soziales Netzwerk* gestolpert. Und zwar wäre die Frage, ob ich "sozial" in diesem Kontext groß- oder kleinschreibe.

Einerseits ist es natürlich erstmal ein Adjektiv, würde also kleingeschrieben. Andererseits spreche ich in diesem Zusammenhang ja nicht von einem Netzwerk, das ich als sozial beschreiben möchte, sondern von dem spezifischen Phänomen *Soziales Netzwerk*; also handelt es sich quasi um einen Sinnzusammenhang, ein feststehendes Konstrukt (es gibt meine ich einen Begriff dafür, der fällt mir aber gerade nicht ein). Schreibe ich es dann groß?

Comment: Die Mehrdeutigkeit als Adjektiv lässt sich nicht wirklich durch die Groß- oder Kleinschreibung wegwischen. Für jemand, der das dann zum ersten Mal liest bleibt es mehrdeutig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich hätte eigentlich auch zum Konstrukt tendiert, aber selbst der Duden schreibt auf seiner Webseite "soziales Netzwerk".

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Social_Media

Comment: Die "ZEIT" schreibt's auch meist (aber nicht immer) klein: http://www.zeit.de/suche/index?q=soziale%20Netzwerke&sort=aktuell&rezension=0&tmode=&from=&to=&p=2

Answer (score 10):

Die Schreibung "Soziales Netzwerk" ist gedeckt durch §64 der Regeln des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung. Diese Regel sieht vor, dass "in bestimmten substantivischen Wortgruppen ... Adjektive großgeschrieben [werden], obwohl keine Eigennamen vorliegen". Es werden als Kategorien Titel und Funktionsbezeichnungen, besondere Kalendertage und fachsprachliche Bezeichnungen in der Botanik und Zoologie angeführt. Als Erweiterung zur dritten Kategorie wird die Großschreibung auch anderen Fachsprachen sowie "Verbindungen mit terminologischem Charakter" eingeräumt. Es ist nicht schwer zu argumentieren, dass Letzteres auf den Begriff "Soziales Netzwerk" angewandt werden kann.

Der Duden steht sich in dieser Frage ein wenig selbst im Weg. "soziales Netzwerk" wird, wenn man dem Link von Thomas Touzimsky folgt, im Duden als Begriffserklärung bzw. als Synonym für das Stichwort *Social Media* verwendet. Die Suche nach "soziales Netzwerk" selbst ergibt wiederum als Treffer *Alumninetzwerk* (= Verbindung von Absolventen einer Universität), *netzwerken*, *MySpace* und *Social Network*. Einen eigenen Eintrag für "soziales Netzwerk" gibt es im Duden nicht. Eine Begründung, warum *Social Media* und *Social Network* groß, soziales Netzwerk aber klein geschrieben werden sollen, liefert die Redaktion nur indirekt, indem sie "sozial" mit "gemeinschaftlich" synonym setzt und damit als normales Attribut gebraucht, das nicht, wie in der Frage angesprochen, im Verein mit "Netzwerk" als stehende Wendung eine **neue Bedeutung** annimmt. Dies ist aber durchaus der Fall.

Denn "gemeinschaftlich" ist erstens ein Wort ohne klare Bedeutung, zweitens gehört es im Deutschen bestenfalls peripher zum Bedeutungsfeld von "sozial". Dieses wird durch die Begriffe *sozialer Wohnbau*, *soziale Einrichtungen*, *Sozialhilfe*, *soziales Engagement*, eine *soziale Ader* haben, auf der anderen Seite *soziale Spannungen* abgesteckt. Sie alle haben mit ungleicher gesellschaftlicher Ressourcenverteilung zu tun und mit dem Anspruch, diese auszugleichen. Als "soziales" Netzwerk würde man im Deutschen ohne Kenntnis des englischen Begriffs "Social Network" und seiner Bedeutung etwas wie einen Zusammenschluss von Institutionen, Organisationen oder auch Privaten zu dem Zweck verstehen, gesellschaftlich und materiell Benachteiligte zu unterstützen. Noch mehr würde dies für "Sozialnetzwerk" und "Sozialmedien" als zusammengesetzte Hauptwörter gelten. Ohne Beifügung von "Netzwerk" oder "Medien" würde das Eigenschaftswort "sozial" auch nicht im Sinn des englischen "social" verstanden werden: als etwas, das mit einer geselligen Zusammenkunft zu tun hat. Ein ähnlicher Effekt ist bei *Sozialverhalten* zu beobachten: trennt man *sozial* als Attribut zu *soziales Verhalten* ab, erhalten wir zumindest eine Doppeldeutigkeit zwischen "helfende Zuwendung" und "Verhalten in der Gruppe".

"A social event" als "soziales Ereignis" zu übersetzen würde Verwirrung hervorrufen, und es ist nicht einmal ein "gesellschaftlicher Anlass" in unserem gehobenen Sinn, sondern das Beisammensein und Interagieren von Menschen. "Gemeinschaftlich", "gesellig", "gemeinsam" sind dafür passende Übersetzungen. Ein Gegenbeispiel, das einzige, das mir einfällt, ist *soziale Kontakte*, doch dieser Begriff hat einen wissenschaftlichen, keinen alltagssprachlichen Unterbau und ist vielleicht ebenfalls von englischsprachiger Literatur angeregt (was noch zu zeigen wäre).

Um Bedeutungskollisionen zu vermeiden, wäre es daher sinnvoll, entgegen dem Beispiel des Duden und im Einklang mit den geltenden Regeln entweder *Soziale Medien* oder *Soziales Netzwerk* zu schreiben oder gleich die beiden Haupteinträge des Duden *Social Media* und *Social Network* zu verwenden, die hier im Gegensatz zur seltsamen anglizistischen Umdeutung von *sozial* keine unnötig homonymbildende Wirkung haben.

Vgl. die Erörterung von Daniel Scholten auf [belleslettres.eu](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/anglizismus-deutsche-sprache.php) zu diesem Thema, der allerdings ein anderes Resümee zieht.

Comment: Der hier referenzierte §64 der Rechtschreibregeln ist in deren aktueller Fassung nicht mehr enthalten. Trotzdem +1 für die Betrachtungen zur Bedeutung von _sozial_ (auch wenn ich der Schlussfolgerung nicht zustimme). Wie der Link zu belleslettres.eu gemeint ist, erschließt sich mir nicht. Falls das Thema irgendwo mal in dem dort eingebetteten einstündigen Video gestreift wird, wäre eine Zeitangabe nett, um direkt hinspringen zu können.

Comment: ich kann der Argumentation nicht ganz folgen. Fürsorglich zu sein ist doch eine bestimmte Form sich gemeinschaftlich zu verhalten, das ist doch kein Gegensatz. Außerdem ist soziales Engagement nicht notwendig auf Ressourcenausgleich gerichtet. "Soziale Kontrolle" wäre ein weiteres Beispiel.

Answer (score 8):

Die diesen Fall betreffende Rechtschreibregel ist [vor wenigen Tagen](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf) neu formuliert worden und [lautet nun](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf)

> §63 In festen Verbindungen aus Adjektiv und Substantiv, die als Ganzes 
>   eine  begriffliche  Einheit  bilden,  richtet  sich  die  Schreibung  des 
>   adjektivischen  Bestandteils  nach  der  jeweils  zugrunde  liegenden 
>   Bedingung.

Die Neufassung des § 63 deckt inhaltlich das ab, was zuvor auf die §§ 63 und 64 verteilt war. Letzterer ist damit entfallen.

Was es mit der "zugrunde liegenden Bedingung" auf sich hat, wird dann im folgenden erklärt. Bei wörtlichem und metaphorischem Gebrauch des Adjektivs gilt Kleinschreibung, bei Titeln, Ehren- und Amtsbezeichnungen sowie Feiertagen gilt Großschreibung. Dazwischen gibt es eine Kann-Regelung:

> (2) Der adjektivische Bestandteil kann großgeschrieben werden
>   (2.1) 
>   in  Verbindungen mit einer idiomatisierten Gesamtbedeutung, das 
>   heißt,   wenn   die   Verbindung   als   Ganzes   eine   neue 
>   lexikalische  Bedeutung  annimmt.  In  diesen  Fällen  kann  durch
>   Großschreibung  der  besondere  Gebrauch  der  Verbindung  zum 
>   Ausdruck  gebracht  werden
>   ...
>   (2.2) in fachsprachlich oder terminologisch gebrauchten Verbindungen

Der Abschnitt 2.1 war bereits früher, sehr ähnlich formuliert, Teil des § 63. Entfallen ist hier aber der Hinweis, dass die Kleinschreibung der Regelfall sei. Die Fälle des Abschnitts 2.2 fielen früher unter den § 64, der mit wenigen Einschränkungen Großschreibung vorsah, die nun aber in vielen Fällen nicht mehr zwingend ist.

*Soziales Netzwerk* ist sicher eine feste Verbindung aus Adjektiv und Substantiv, die eine begiffliche Einheit bildet. Nach der Neuregelung ist klar, dass das Adjektiv nur noch in wenigen, hier nicht zutreffenden Fällen groß geschrieben werden *muss*. Mit Kleinschreibung liegst Du also garantiert nicht falsch.

Ob es sich um einen Begriff aus einer Fachsprache handelt (und wenn ja: welcher - Wikipedia z.B. ordnet es [4 verschiedenen Domänen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soziales_Netzwerk) zu), musst Du mit dem jeweiligen Kontext und Deinem eigenen Fachwissen selbst entscheiden. Zu beachten ist, dass laut §63 E2 nicht jede Fachsprache von der Möglichkeit der Großschreibung Gebrauch macht und es deshalb Wendungen gibt, die immer klein geschrieben werden. Das [Wörterverzeichnis](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Woerterverzeichnis_2017.pdf) nennt dazu u.a. *irrationale Zahl* und *saurer Regen*.

Der zweite Fall, der nach (2.2) Großschreibung ermöglicht, sind "terminologisch gebrauchte Verbindungen". Was damit gemeint ist, wird beim Blick auf die Beispiele in den Regeln klar(er): *erste/Erste Hilfe*, *gelber/Gelber Sack* - das sind die "festen Konstrukte", die Du in Deiner Frage vermutlich gemeint hast; stehende Begriffe, die alltäglich, nicht fachsprachlich sind, die aber trotzdem eine klare, eng umrissene Bedeutung haben. Letztlich ist das wohl Auslegungssache (ich habe selbst eben versucht, "terminologisch" zu interpretieren), aber ich denke, dass *Soziales Netzwerk* auch in diese Kategorie fällt. Groß schreiben würde ich es aber vor allem dann, wenn daraus ein Mehrwert für das Verständnis entsteht, denn wenn Google mich nicht in die Irre führt, scheint die Kleinschreibung deutlich häufiger vorzukommen.

---

**Exkurs:** Käme auch noch (2.1) als Legitimation für Großschreibung in Betracht (also die *idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung*), d.h steckt in der Verbindung aus *sozial* und *Netzwerk* eine neue Bedeutung, die sich nicht aus den beiden Teilen ergibt? Das hängt vor allem an der Bedeutung von *sozial*. Martin Schwehla hat diese [in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22298/9091) ausführlich erörtert. Tatsächlich legt der [Duden in seiner Darstellung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sozial#Bedeutung1a) einen großen Schwerpunkt auf *sozial* für einen politischen und ökonomischen Kontext. Möglicherweise sieht man es dort ähnlich wie Martin, dass *sozial* als neutrales Wort für Interaktionen und Beziehungen nur in Fachsprachen (vor allem Soziologie und [Zoologie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sozial#Bedeutung1a)) gebräuchlich ist.

Ich finde hingegen, dass Wendungen wie *soziale Kontakte*, [*soziale Beziehungen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soziale_Beziehung) oder [*soziale Interaktionen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soziale_Interaktion) durchaus allgemein- und unmissverständlich sind - letzteres aber nicht zuletzt dadurch, dass hier jeweils auch nochmal das Substantiv einen Hinweis darauf liefert, wie die Fügung zu verstehen ist. *Netzwerk* ist da neutraler, man könnte *soziales Netzwerk* auch als Gruppierung verstehen, die sich dem ökonomischen Ausgleich widmet. Aber letztlich erklärt das eher den Wunsch nach Abgrenzung durch Großschreibung, liefert aber kein Argument, um Abschnitt 2.1 anwenden zu können. Wenn ich mir den Satz anschaue

> Er pflegt soziale Kontakte vor allem über soziale Netzwerke.

dann sehe ich keinen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Fügungen - und dann kann ich auch in

> Freundschaften pflegt er vor allem über soziale Netzwerke.

keine *neue lexikalische Bedeutung* für die Verbindung aus *sozial* und *Netzwerk* annehmen.

Comment: Bei Satz 2 mit den Freundschaften denke ich bei sozialen Netzwerken an Fußballverein und dergleichen, bei Satz 1 dagegen an Facebook & Twitter. Inhaltlich sagen die Sätze ja ganz unterschiedliches aus, aber nicht, oder nicht nur, weil es hier um soziale Kontakte, da um Freundschaften geht, sondern weil mal "vor allem", mal "nur" verwendet wird. Wie sonst soll man soziale Kontakte pflegen, wenn nicht über sozialel Netzwerke? Man trifft die Person also auch einzeln, also nicht als Kollegen, Mitschüler oder Sportkameraden - dann ist es wohl eine Art Freundschaft.

Comment: Deine Absätze über "fachsprachliche Begriffe" hören sich so an, als ob man solche Zusammensetzungen in Fachterminologie immer nach Gusto gross oder klein schreiben dürfte - Nein, diese § fasse ich anders auf: Die Regeln halten sich hier raus und sagen, dass man groß schreiben *kann*, wenn die Fachterminologen das so beschließen. Es ist also nicht deine Entscheidung, sondern der gängige Gebrauch in der Fachsprache, der das festlegt. Ich finde, das ist ein Unterschied. Ansonsten könnte ich jeden Fehler mit "Fachterminologie" rechtfertigen.

Comment: @tofro **Alle** Beispiele zu §63 2.2, die ausdrücklich einem Fachgebiet zugeordnet sind, sind in beiden Schreibweisen angegeben. Deshalb glaube ich, dass Deine Interpretation falsch ist. Selbst wenn die Mediziner immer _Multiple Sklerose_ groß schreiben, kann ich es in einem "normalen" Text klein schreiben. Die Fachgebietsregeln gelten innerhalb der Fachgebiete. Als Otto Normalschreiber bin ich da nicht dran gebunden.

Comment: Das Beispiel geht an sich andersrum: Würden die Mediziner *multiple Sklerose* immer kleinschreiben (ich weiß, das tun sie nicht...), kannst du dich nicht mit "Fachsprache" rausreden, dass du es groß schreiben darfst. Soll heißen "Fachsprache" kann die Kleinschreibungsregel brechen, dann muß die Großschreibung in der Fachterminologie aber auch gängig sein.

Comment: @tofro Ich wollte ja schon fast einwenden, dass der Fall irrelevant sein dürfte, habe dann aber den zuvor überlesenen Hinweis E2 entdeckt und im Wörterverzeichnis ein paar Beispiele gefunden. Die Passage ist jetzt überarbeitet. Danke für den Hinweis!

Comment: @userunknown Den Unterschied "nur" vs. "vor allem" habe ich beseitigt. Mir geht es in dem Exkurs (inzwischen als solcher gekennzeichnet) nur um die Frage, ob hier die Kriterien für eine _idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung_ vorliegen. Ich würde auch den letzten Satz in Richtung FB&Co verstehen, einfach weil "sozial" für mich sonst redundant wäre - "privat" oder "beruflich" würden hingegen eine nähere Bestimmung geben. Prinzipiell finde ich Deinen Einwand, dass der Begriff auch anders verstanden werden kann, aber berechtigt. Die Klausel 2.2 kann da mMn nach helfen, Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.

Comment: M.E. ist es klar ein Fall von 2.1, danke für die Ausführungen @Matthias. Es gibt z.B. keine asozialen Netzwerke, oder?!

Comment: @Thomas Na ja, es gibt auch keinen süßen Regen, und wir reden nicht von häufigen Erden oder unnatürlichen Personen - trotzdem sind die entsprechenden Wendungen kein Fall für 2.1 und werden immer klein geschrieben. Ansonsten: gern geschehen. Mir war es vor allem wichtig, die Hintergründe zu beleuchten. Anwenden muss es dann jeder selbst.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann beim besten Willen keinen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen *sozialem Netzwerk*, *sozialen Medien* und beispielsweise *sozialem Wohnungsbau* erkennen (bei letzterem ist die Kleinschreibung unzweifelhaft), außer dass die beiden ersteren direkt aus dem Englischen übersetzt sind und die die Hauptbedeutung von *social* nicht mit der von *sozial* identisch ist (siehe die Namen deutscher Parteien mit "S").

Die saubere Lösung wäre daher die Verwendung eines zündenderen Adjektivs als *sozial* bei der Übersetzung gewesen, aber solche Sprachkreativität ist momentan nicht besonders gefragt, wenn denn überhaupt noch vorhanden.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kann die Diskussion nicht gut nachvollziehen. Der englische Ausdruck *social media* wird im Deutschen oft mit *Soziales Netzwerk* übersetzt. Das sind Facebook und Co.; wir wissen alle, was gemeint ist.

Wenn sich ein paar Menschen zusammentun, um sich gegenseitig oder auch andere sozial zu unterstützen, bauen sie – auch ohne Computer – ein *soziales Netzwerk* auf. Dieser Unterschied äußert sich in Groß- und Kleinschreibung, ganz einfach!

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Inwiefern stellt das keine Antwort dar? Es wird klar dargestellt und begründet, worin OP den Unterschied sieht.

Answer (score 0):

Ich orientiere mich als Jurist gerne auch an der Schreibweise des Gesetzgebers. Soziale Netzwerke sind zentraler Regelungsgegenstand des [Netzwerkdurchsetzungsgesetzes (NetzDG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/netzdg/BJNR335210017.html). Dort hat man sich – sehr wahrscheinlich richtigerweise – für die Kleinschreibung entschieden.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Bitte nach Möglichkeit den relevanten Teil des Links - hier den Satz aus dem Gesetz - als Zitat einfügen. Das macht einerseits die Antwort meist verständlicher, andererseits die Antwort vom Verschwinden der verlinkten Seite weniger abhängig. Auch wenn es in diesem konkreten Fall eher unwahrscheinlich ist, dass sie offline geht :)